# Проблема автозагрузка PHP

Tags: php

Не получается подключить автозагрузку. Как правильно писать код для автозагрузки?
Класс

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
class Article extends Model {

    public $title;
    public $content;
    public $author;
    public static function findLatestNews()
    {
        $db = new Db;
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM  news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3';
        return $db->query($sql,[], static::class);
    }

};
```

Файл с автозагрузкой

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
});
```

Подключение

```html
<?php
require __DIR__.'/autoload.php';
$article= new App\Models\Article();
$article->title = 'Мишки любят конфеты с коньяком';
?>
```

Структура файлов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**И получаю ошибки**

> Warning: include(App\Models\Article.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in
>   C:\OSPanel\domains\2-php-7-2\App\autoload.php on line 3
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'App\Models\Article.php' for
>   inclusion
>   (include_path='.;c:/ospanel/modules/php/PHP-7.2-x64;c:/ospanel/modules/php/PHP-7.2-x64/PEAR/pear')
>   in C:\OSPanel\domains\2-php-7-2\App\autoload.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Models\Article' not found in
>   C:\OSPanel\domains\2-php-7-2\App\index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in C:\OSPanel\domains\2-php-7-2\App\index.php on line 3

**Если файлы лежат в одной директории и в начале классов не прописывать namespace то автозагрузка работает корректно**

Comment: Вы уверены, что файлы лежат в корне ? с файлов автозагрузки. Иначе нужно указывать полный путь до классов, которые хотите подгружать.

Comment: Посмел бы вам рекомендовать использовать composer . Как минимум возможно подключить любую библиотеку, ну и само собой ваши файлы будут подгружаться,  нужно будет всего лишь добавить одну строку в composer.json

Comment: Файл автозагрузки лежит в папке App, классы в папке App/Models.

Answer (score 1):

Не претендую на истину, однако осмелюсь написать...

Если вы посмотрите на современные библиотеки да и вообще на проекты, то увидите что сейчас везде и повсеместно используется `composer` . По сути composer представляет из себя то что называют "менеджер зависимостей". В `javascript` это например `npm` или `yarn` . В `Python` это `pip`. В `PHP` это `composer`.
Поверьте, если вы не собираетесь всю жизнь ковырять говносайты построенные на joomla или (о боги!) 1сBitrix, то самое время не пытаться городить автозагрузчики (при этом не очень разбираясь, как я понимаю, в PSR0, PSR4), а использовать то, что используют в общем то те ребята, которые задают нынче моду в PHP (тут я и про Symfony и про Laravel и про Yii в конце концов, хотя последнее в руках не держал).

Я говорю о стандартах, которые в российском сегменте интернета почему то пытаются игнорировать, тем самым генерируя огроменное количество говна, которое как раз и выливается в виде Битрикса.

Не буду описывать "пошагово", наверняка вы разберетесь если захотите. Тем не менее смею заверить что с помощью данного инструмента вы сможете очень быстро и прозрачно импортировать себе в проект нужные вам библиотеки и сосредоточитесь на разработке, а не на том что вам придется думать как сделать автозагрузку своего проекта. С уважением! :)

Answer (score 0):

Сперва в  файле `index.php` создать константу которая будет хранить путь к корню проекта:

```
define('ROOT_PATH', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

И вот вам пример который позволит понять как это реализовать:

```
function autoloader($className)
{
    try {
        $path = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className);
        $file = ROOT_PATH . $path . '.php';
        if (!is_file($file))
            throw new \Exception ($file.' file not found');
        include ($file);
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
}
spl_autoload_register('autoloader');
```

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно для вашего примера, нужно просто указать `\`

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    include '\\' . $class_name . '.php';
});
```

Comment: Увы, не помогло:(

Comment: Нет((((((((((((

Comment: @Александр чтобы решить вопрос, надо просто вместо `include` разок прописать `var_dump('\\' . $class_name . '.php';);` и посмотреть что за путь, можете сюда его кинуть

Comment: Если вместо переменной,подставить имя класса,который я хочу подгрузить получается так "C:\OSPanel\domains\2-php-7-2\App\Article.php".

Comment: @Александр `$article= new App\Models\Article();` а `include` замените на `var_dump(__DIR__ . '\\' . $class_name . '.php';)` и покажите результат

Comment: "C:\OSPanel\domains\2-php-7-2\App\App\Models\Article.php"

Comment: @Александр вот вам и ответ: `include '..\\' . $class_name . '.php';`

Comment: Cначала так и было написано. Не работает

Comment: @Александр В `index.php` - в самом начале вставьте строчку `define('ROOT_PATH', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);`, потом `include ROOT_PATH . $class_name . '.php';`

Comment: Если и так не заработает значит не правильно вы нам что-то сказали.

Comment: Не работае.  Все у меня так и есть,как в шапке описано. Я подключил каждый класс просто "вручную" в итоге. Все норм,без ошибок. Не понимаю,почему автозагрузка не работает.